# PDO execution get time out

Tags: php, optimization, pdo, execution-time

I converted my native PHP code into PDO as is it more secured compared to the native one, now i'm having problem in executing my code when I'm trying to retrieve more than 10 records. I always got this fatal error:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/user/public_html/folder/pdo/user_hashing.php on line 13.

This is my code:

```
$pdo = Database::getInstance();
$stmt = $pdo->db->prepare("SELECT email, name, user_id FROM Users where page='' and reset='' order by user_id asc");
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetchObject())
{
    $id= $row->user_id;
    $str= $row->name."-".$row->user_id;
    $hash=md5($str) ;
    $stmt2 = $pdo->db->prepare("UPDATE Users SET request='1', reset='1', userhash=:userHash where page='' and user_id='$id' limit 1");           
    $stmt2->bindParam(':userHash', $hash);
    $stmt2->execute();
    unset($stmt2);
}
unset($pdo);
```

Everytime the script run, it will only retrieve and update up to 10 records. After, that I will get the execution time error.

Is there any other way to prevent this? I never got this kind of error using native PHP. And, its not a good to adjust the memory limit in php.ini. That is what i have known before.

Comment: two side notes. 1. You are using PDO the same ugly ways as old mysql ext, which renders whole transition useless. 2. for such an update, single update query is enough. 3. raw unsalted md5() considered too weak a hash

Comment: @YourCommonSense, yes I'm aware that md5 are too weak.ByCrypt is the recommended. I have used ByCrypt instead of MD5